# Android: intelligent way of sizing UI components for all screens?

Tags: android

I've been having trouble finding a generic way to size UI components so they look good on all devices.  I have some ideas but could use any feedback on them or suggestions for better strategies.

Take a simple situation like a dialog with a single EditText which a user will enter a fairly long String into. On smaller devices I would like the EditText to be as wide as possible (because its likely that the maximum size possible on these devices isn't all that large). However, if I set the width of this EditText to FILL_PARENT, the dialog will look silly on tablets, because it will be much, much wider than it needs to be.  Also, setting the width to some hard coded DIP value, like 500, isn't great because it doesn't maximize available space on smaller devices, won't expand to take up additional space if the device is rotated, and could be an issue on devices narrowers than 500 DIP.

What I would like to do is approximate the behavior FILL_PARENT by hardcoding the width of the EditText to of the screen's width, but to prevent the EditText from growing to wide on large devices by not allowing the width to be larger than some DIP value, like 500.

I have encountered 2 problems with this strategy:

1: If I set the EditText's width to the screen's width, the EditText doesn't fit on the screen (as shown in the below image).  I fixed this by setting the width to 90% of screen width, but this is questionable (what if the device's dialogs have larger margins around them?).

[image]

2: My app sets android:configChanges flag in its application manifest such that dialogs don't get dismissed on rotation.  But this means that dialogs don't get resized on rotation.  So, if the device rotates from landscape to portrait while the dialog is visible, then the EditText will be too wide for the screen; and if it goes the opposite direction, then the EditText will not take up all the available space.  I guess this would be fixable by relaying out my dialog on rotate, but it seems painful/ugly for my Activity to have to keep track of the visible Dialog and force it to relayout on rotation (particularly because each dialog would then have re-populate any field values when after relayout).

So, any thoughts on improving my solution, or on alternatives?

```
class SampleDialog extends Dialog
{
    public SampleDialog(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);

        setContentView(getContentView());
    }

    private View getContentView()
    {

        TextView label = new TextView(getContext());
        label.setText("A label:");

        int fiveHundredDips = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 500, activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        float width = .9f * display.getWidth();
        Math.min(width, fiveHundredDips);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        EditText editText = new EditText(getContext());
        editText.setLayoutParams(linearParams);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        layout.addView(label);
        layout.addView(editText);

        return layout;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use different folders in your resources folder, which define different qualifiers for different devices. You can then specify say on a small device you would like a dimension to be 'x' big, and on a tablet to be 'x' big.

Another solution would be to programatically detect if the device is a Tablet, and perform actions based on that.

I would recommend you look into resource qualifiers, which are a very powerful tool in Android.

Comment: This is a good idea.  Do something like: if device is a tablet, set width to 400ish DIP, otherwise use FILL_PARENT.  Any advice on determining a good DIP width for tablets?

Comment: Test your layouts in eclipse layout designer? Best way I can think of short of buying a shiny new tab :p

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the android:minWidth property. It's available on TextView as well as others. It seems the minWidth (set using dip units) would be a good option for you. You can make the text boxes large enough but not too large.

These values can be set programmatically. You might also find the following code useful in determining what values you want to use for the minWidth:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Log.d("density", metrics.density);
Log.d("width dip", (int) (metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density));
Log.d("height dip", (int) (metrics.heightPixels / metrics.density));
```

Comment: Actually, what I would like to use is maxWidth with FILL_PARENT, so that I could set the EditText to a width of FILL_PARENT, but ensure that it isn't wider than some maxWidth value. However, when I try this, the EditText is very small (probably the EditText's minimum possible size), presumably because setting FILL_PARENT for View is not effective when the View is a Dialog's child.

Comment: Additionally, even if I force the dialog to FILL_PARENT, so that I can utilize FILL_PARENT with the EditText, it appears that the MaxWidth is ignored (the EditText always takes up the full screen, regardless of what I use for setMaxWidth())